# Why am i having issues with this curl?

Tags: php, curl

I want to change the response of an API if an incorrect value is typed..

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['q']))
    {

    $q = ($_GET['q']);
    $curl = curl_init();
    
     curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.me.co/bank/resolve?account_number=".$q."&bank_code=".$bcode."",
      
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
     CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"Authorization: Bearer demo_03a647487df8a50d343aeb66d2a7305yhfkfllba",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = 
    curl_error($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
     }
     ?>
```

Now  **$response** is the ouput and irrespective of wat input the user types the **$response** will ouptut something. If the users input is wrong, it will show a php error which will scare the user.

**$q** is the users input and have tried using something like

```
   if(!$response)
    {
     echo "incorrect";
     }
```

The only thing that worked was turning off the error reporting for that page which i do not want cos i dont want the user to proceed.

In summary what i want is to customise the error from **$response** if the user input is wrong. Thanks as usual.

Comment: So what issue exists in your cURL if you're getting the response?

Comment: Something like this and more..   **Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in /storage/ssd5/642/13941642/public_html/go/cpanel/Otransfer/trans/getuser.php on line 61

Notice: Trying to get property 'account_name' of non-object in /storage/ssd5/642/13941642/public_html/go/cpanel/Otransfer/trans/getuser.php on line 61**  . Thats because the user input is incorrect. If it was correct. Would have displayed the needed thing

Comment: Ok but do you have access to the API code?

Comment: What is the http status code you get with curl_getinfo() ?

Comment: Ok. Tanx. I am able to see the issues. Thanks once again @vivek